# Maven Parallel Build - Sequence some modules

Tags: java, maven, parallel-processing

I have a multi-module maven project and looking to leverage the parallel build feature in Maven 3. But some of the modules lay the groundwork for future modules (when built sequentially, like creating some directories, downloading some non-maven jars etc). Is there a way for me to control the parallelism partially so that the build starts of sequentially and then goes parallel and eventually converge to a final module that does aggregation and cannot be run before the others?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but I think it should be possible.  The downside is you will have to control that branch/join logic yourself by running `mvn` multiple times.

First, check out this article for how to do parallel builds: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Parallel+builds+in+Maven+3

Now when it comes to building individual modules, you should use this command line option:

```
 -pl,--projects <arg>                   Comma-delimited list of specified
                                        reactor projects to build instead
                                        of all projects. A project can be
                                        specified by [groupId]:artifactId
                                        or by its relative path.
```

I think you will need to run the `mvn` command multiple times.  Let me know if you need more info.

---

*Side Note: [Consider this line](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Parallel+builds+in+Maven+3)*

> *This build-mode analyzes your project's dependency graph and schedules modules that can be built in parallel according to the dependency graph of your project.*

*You may not need to do any branch/join logic.  See if it works without it.*

Comment: Great. Will give this a shot. I did think about the dependency graph approach. But since not all artificats generated by the projects running in sequence are inserted into maven, having some difficulty in defining dependency for them.

Comment: So I tried a very similar approach, but rather than listing the modules one by one, I created profiles and activated them on each instance of maven build. Seems to work for now. Will still mark your answer as a possible solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Just add a dependency on the pom (pom) we use this to order our docker builds (images depend on base images that need to built earlier)

Comment: This is correct and the easiest method. Even though one module might not have java class dependency on other module, if that other module is a prerequisite, then it should be listed as dependency.